# How to extract arbitrary iOS application Data from iPhone 11?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

I'm running iOS 14.0.1 on an iPhone 11 and I have an appication that is no longer on the App Store. (By the developer, who abandoning the app.)

The app in question was a manga app that let people read and favorite mangas that they liked. I am trying to find a way to get my list of favorite mangas from the app without manually typing out every mangas name (which for me is 2222 mangas long).

Is there a general way to access specific app data on an iPhone that doesn’t rely on knowing exactly how a specific developer made their app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### iTunes File Sharing

Some apps share their documents folder through iTunes file sharing. It's up to the developer to enable this functionality. If this is enabled, you can find the app's documents folder in Finder by selecting your iPhone in the sidebar and choosing the apps tab. Files can be transferred to your computer by dragging them to your desired copy destination.

### Backup

Make a local backup of your device in Finder and use an app like [iMazing](https://imazing.com/iphone-backup-browser-extractor) to extract files from the backup.

### Jailbreak

If your device is jailbroken, you can access the file system with [Filza](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.tigisoftware.filza/) and share files as you would files in the Files app (AirDrop etc).

Comment: I would append "Apple Configurator" app to the "Backup" section list